# Having trouble with Linq query from complex JSON Data C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am attempting to query JSON data from an NBA API to create List so I can add the range to my DB the `.SelectMany` statement returns only one variable I have no build errors but run into an error when running code. I believe the error lies with my statements but I am not sure. I can't seem to find the answer on google.

Any help is appreciated I'm pulling my hair with this. Attached is my Linq query, JSON data, and Game Class.

Linq Query:

```
var json = response.Content;
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
List<Game> games = (from g in jObject["api"]["games"]
                
select new Game(
    (int)g["gameId"],
    (string)g["startTimeUTC"],
    null,
    (int)g["hTeam"]["teamId"],
    (int)g["vTeam"]["teamId"],
                    
    (int)g["hTeam"]["score"]["points"],  // getting error here "input string invalid"
    (int)g["vTeam"]["score"]["points"])).ToList();
```

JSON Data

```
{"api":{"status":200,"message":"GET games\/seasonYear\/2020","results":1168,"filters":["seasonYear","league","gameId","teamId","date","live"],"games":[{"seasonYear":"2020","league":"standard","gameId":"8133","startTimeUTC":"2020-12-12T00:00:00.000Z","endTimeUTC":"2020-12-12T02:29:00.000Z","arena":"State Farm Arena","city":"Atlanta","country":"USA","clock":"","gameDuration":"2:19","currentPeriod":"4\/4","halftime":"0","EndOfPeriod":"0","seasonStage":"1","statusShortGame":"3","statusGame":"Finished","vTeam":{"teamId":"26","shortName":"ORL","fullName":"Orlando Magic","nickName":"Magic","logo":"https:\/\/upload.wikimedia.org\/wikipedia\/fr\/b\/bd\/Orlando_Magic_logo_2010.png","score":{"points":"116"}},"hTeam":{"teamId":"1","shortName":"ATL","fullName":"Atlanta Hawks","nickName":"Hawks","logo":"https:\/\/upload.wikimedia.org\/wikipedia\/fr\/e\/ee\/Hawks_2016.png","score":{"points":"112"}}},{"seasonYear":"2020","league":"standard","gameId":"8134","startTimeUTC":"2020-12-12T00:00:00.000Z","endTimeUTC":"2020-12-12T02:32:00.000Z","arena":"Little Caesars Arena","city":"Detroit","country":"USA","clock":"","gameDuration":"2:19","currentPeriod":"4\/4","halftime":"0","EndOfPeriod":"0","seasonStage":"1","statusShortGame":"3","statusGame":"Finished","vTeam":{"teamId":"24","shortName":"NYK","fullName":"New York Knicks","nickName":"Knicks","logo":"https:\/\/upload.wikimedia.org\/wikipedia\/fr\/d\/dc\/NY_Knicks_Logo_2011.png","score":{"points":"90"}},"hTeam":{"teamId":"10","shortName":"DET","fullName":"Detroit Pistons","nickName":"Pistons","logo":"https:\/\/upload.wikimedia.org\/wikipedia\/en\/thumb\/1\/1e\/Detroit_Pistons_logo.svg\/1200px-Detroit_Pistons_logo.svg.png","score":{"points":"84"}}},{"seasonYear":"2020","league":"standard","gameId":"8135","startTimeUTC":"2020-12-12T01:00:00.000Z","endTimeUTC":"2020-12-12T03:23:00.000Z","arena":"United Center","city":"Chicago","country":"USA","clock":"","gameDuration":"2:09","currentPeriod":"4\/4","halftime":"0","EndOfPeriod":"0","seasonStage":"1","statusShortGame":"3","statusGame":"Finished","vTeam":{"teamId":"14","shortName":"HOU","fullName":"Houston Rockets","nickName":"Rockets","logo":"https:\/\/upload.wikimedia.org\/wikipedia\/fr\/thumb\/d\/de\/Houston_Rockets_logo_2003.png\/330px-Houston_Rockets_logo_2003.png","score":{"points":"125"}},"hTeam":{"teamId":"6","shortName":"CHI","fullName":"Chicago Bulls","nickName":"Bulls","logo":"https:\/\/upload.wikimedia.org\/wikipedia\/fr\/thumb\/d\/d1\/Bulls_de_Chicago_logo.svg\/1200px-Bulls_de_Chicago_logo.svg.png","score":{"points":"104"}}}]}}
```

Game Class

```
public class Game
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "gameId")]
    public int GameID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "startTimeUTC")]

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public bool? Favorite { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "api/games/hTeam/score/points")]
    public int HomeScore { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "api/games/vTeam/score/points")]
    public int AwayScore { get; set; }

    public int TotalScore
    {
        get
        { return (HomeScore + AwayScore); }
    }

    [Required]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "api/games/hTeam/teamId")]
    public int HomeID { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    [ForeignKey("HomeID")]
    public Team HomeTeam {get; set;}

    [Required]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "api/games/vTeam/teamId")]

    public int AwayID { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [ForeignKey("AwayID")]
    public Team AwayTeam { get; set; }

    public List<GameBet> GameBet { get; set; }

    public List<PlayerGame> PlayerGame { get; set; }

    public Game(int gameId, DateTime date, bool? favorite, int homeID, int awayID, int homeScore, int awayScore) 
    {
        this.GameID = gameId;
        this.Date = date;
        this.Favorite = favorite;
        this.HomeScore = homeScore;
        this.AwayScore = awayScore;
        this.HomeID = homeID;
        this.AwayID = awayID;
        this.GameBet = new List<GameBet>();
        this.PlayerGame = new List<PlayerGame>();
    }

    public Game() { }
}
```

Comment: Json string is not valid. It raise an exception. Can you correct it?

Comment: @M.Hassan I fixed the JSON string on the question. Sorry it had over 2000 games in the whole string so I just copied a chunk of it.

Comment: It seems that the class don't match the json string. I have generated a [classes](https://gist.github.com/moh-hassan/b447ae81879419d1f309c26e5db950e5) that match you json. It may help and you can add the attributes to it.

Comment: @M.Hassan is this the only way to do this? I considered doing this so I could just use the deserialize function but I would have to rewrite a lot of code and unitTests. I used the linq query to get team data and was able to select the elements I needed for the class structure I had already written I was hoping to do the same for this. I fixed the syntax for the linq query and now the only issue is retrieving the score.

Comment: Simply, you get the rootObject, and you can access all games.It's save `var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the class don't match the json string.

I generated set of classes that match your json string. You can find [here](https://gist.github.com/moh-hassan/b447ae81879419d1f309c26e5db950e5) and add attributes as needed.
Then you can access the games and score simply using typed classes instead of using `Jobject`.

Example:

```cs
 var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
            var games = rootObject.api.games;
            foreach (var g in games)
            {
                var score = g.vTeam.score.points;
                Console.WriteLine($"{g.city}  {score}");
            }
```